# Loading hdf5 files into python xarrays

Tags: python, hdf5, dask, h5py, python-xarray

The python module xarray greatly supports loading/mapping netCDF files, even lazily with dask.

The data source I have to work with are thousands of hdf5 files, with lots of groups, datasets, attributes - all created with h5py.

**The Question is**: How can I load (or even better with dask, lazily map) hdf5 data (datasets, metadata,...) into an xarray dataset structure?

Has anybody experience with that or came across a similar issue?
Thank you!

Comment: It is one of the [basic functions](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html) - you should read the doc, try it and report back here if you have any problem. As it stands, this is not really a SO-like question, you may see negative votes.

Comment: @mdurant thank you for your comment. I will try to formulate my question clearer.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `xarray` module, However, `h5py` accesses HDF5 data as `numpy` record arrays. So, you simply need to access a hdf5 dataset as a record array and manipulate the data into a xarray dataset format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible solution to this is to open the hdf5-file using netCDF4 in diskless non-persistence mode:

```
ncf = netCDF4.Dataset(hdf5file, diskless=True, persist=False)
```

Now you can inspect the file contents including `groups`.

After that you can make use of `xarray.backends.NetCDF4DataStore` to open the wanted hdf5-groups (`xarray` can only get hold of one hdf5-group at a time):

```
nch = ncf.groups.get('hdf5-name')
xds = xarray.open_dataset(xarray.backends.NetCDF4DataStore(nch))
```

This will give you a dataset `xds` with all attributes and variables (datasets) of the 
group `hdf5-name`. Note that you will not get access to sub-groups. You would need to claim subgroups by the same mechanism. If you want to apply `dask`, you would need to add the keyword `chunking` with wanted values.

There is no (real) automatism for decoding data like this could be done for NetCDF files. If you have a integer compressed 2d variable (dataset) `var` with some attributes `gain` and `offset` you can add the NetCDF specific attributes `scale_factor` and `add_offset` to the variable:

```
var = xds['var']
var.attrs['scale_factor'] = var.attrs.get('gain')
var.attrs['add_offset'] = var.attrs.get('offset')
ds = xarray.decode_cf(xds)
```

This will decode your variable using netcdf mechanisms.

Additionally you could try to give the extracted dimension useful names (you will get something like `phony_dim_0`, `phony_dim_1`, ..., `phony_dim_N`) and assign new (as in example) or existing variables/coordinates to those dimensions to gain as much of the xarray machinery:

```
var = xds['var']
var.attrs['scale_factor'] = var.attrs.get('gain')
var.attrs['add_offset'] = var.attrs.get('offset')
dims = var.dims
xds['var'] = var.rename({dims[0]: 'x', dims[1]: 'y'})
xds = xds.assign({'x': (['x'], xvals, xattrs)})
xds = xds.assign({'y': (['y'], yvals, yattrs)})
ds = xarray.decode_cf(xds)
```

References:

- [netCDF4 Dataset](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Dataset)
- [xarray.backends.NetCDF4DataStore](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.backends.NetCDF4DataStore.html)
- [xarray.decode_cf](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.decode_cf.html?highlight=xarray.decode_cf())

Comment: This looks like a good approach, except that I keep getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dimensions'` when trying to open my hdf5 file. Was it written in a way that's not compatible with netcdf?

Comment: @TomCho Which versions of xarray, hdf5, libnetcd and netCDF4 are you using. And what is the code and the error message?